# Detecting local DNS server, under Linux

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

I want to disable my router's DNS service, and use my own dnsmasq
server on local LAN as a DNS caching server, for all other machines,
would it be possible?

I.e., is there any mechanism for all other machines on LAN to detect
that there is a local DNS server (and use it automatically if so)?

This is:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: with DHCP, you can assign DNS -- if all of your hosts are static, there is no mechanism for them to "discover" and overwrite their static config.  You would have to write that up yourself and implement it on all hosts on the net.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "auto discover" mechanism for dns servers, however if you have dhcp (which it sounds like you do on your router), you can set the dnsmasq server as the dns server in the dhcp config.

If you don't have dhcp (all your hosts are static) you would have to set the dns server on every computer